# problem with rosmake files

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using groovy on ubuntu 12.04.
I downloaded rbx_vol_1 package through svn checkout http://ros-by-example.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rbx_vol_1 ,then I rosmake it:  rosmake rbx_vol_1,  rosmake results as follows,

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['rbx_vol_1']                               
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/yanglan/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140412-113116
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['rbx_vol_1'] to:
['rbx1_description', 'rbx1_bringup', 'rbx1_speech', 'rbx1_dynamixels', 'rbx1_nav', 'rbx1_apps', 'rbx1_vision']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> catkin [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< catkin ROS_NOBUILD in package catkin
 No Makefile in package catkin
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genmsg [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package genmsg
 No Makefile in package genmsg
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genlisp [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genlisp ROS_NOBUILD in package genlisp
 No Makefile in package genlisp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genpy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genpy ROS_NOBUILD in package genpy
 No Makefile in package genpy
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> gencpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< gencpp ROS_NOBUILD in package gencpp
 No Makefile in package gencpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_generation [ make ]                            
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_generation ROS_NOBUILD in package message_generation
 No Makefile in package message_generation
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospack [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospack ROS_NOBUILD in package rospack
 No Makefile in package rospack
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
 No Makefile in package roslib
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common
 No Makefile in package cpp_common
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime
 No Makefile in package rostime
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits
 No Makefile in package roscpp_traits
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                          
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
 No Makefile in package roscpp_serialization
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> message_runtime [ make ]                               
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< message_runtime ROS_NOBUILD in package message_runtime
 No Makefile in package message_runtime
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
 No Makefile in package std_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs
 No Makefile in package rosgraph_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit
 No Makefile in package rosunit
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
 No Makefile in package rosconsole
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
 No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp
 No Makefile in package xmlrpcpp
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph
 No Makefile in package rosgraph
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
 No Makefile in package rospy
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> diagnostic_msgs [ make ]                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< diagnostic_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package diagnostic_msgs
 No Makefile in package diagnostic_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rbx1_speech [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
 No Makefile in package roscpp
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> sound_play [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< sound_play ROS_NOBUILD in package sound_play           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2
 No Makefile in package opencv2
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs
 No Makefile in package geometry_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs
 No Makefile in package sensor_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< cv_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge
 No Makefile in package cv_bridge
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rbx1_vision [ make ]                                   
[ rosmake ] All 21 linesbx1_speech: 0.5 sec ] [ r... [ 2 Active 28/68 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package rbx1_speech
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rospack deps-manifests rbx1_speech
  [rospack] Error: package/stack 'rbx1_speech' depends on non-existent package 'pocketsphinx' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'rbx1_speech'.
    Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
    broken dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package rbx1_speech written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/yanglan/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140412-113116/rbx1_speech/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rbx1_speech [FAIL] [ 0.52 seconds ]                    
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package rbx1_speech. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rbx1_vision [PASS] [ 2.80 seconds ]                    
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 30 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/yanglan/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140412-113116
```

thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152211/problem-with-rosmake-files/) by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you read the error message? It tells you that you are missing a package, namely `pocketsphinx`.

Do `rosdep update` and then `rosdep check rbx1_speech` and see what it has to say.

**Edit:** Hm... not sure why rosdep does not recognize it, but try `apt-get install ros-groovy-pocketsphinx` and then the rosmake command again.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on 2014-04-12**:
it says,All system dependencies have been satisified
ERROR[rbx1_speech]: resource not found [pocketsphinx]